# Missing Testimonial tab in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, missing-template

[image]

The "testimonial" tab in Wordpress Admin's menu is missing.
Does anyone know how to put it back or why it disappeared?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Sorry for the large image. I forgot to resize it.

Comment: are using org or .com

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no testimonials menu in wordpress admin sidebar.
You must have been using a wordpress plugin or widget on your website.

To have the testimonials menu back again, you need to reinstall the plugin.

[Check out this URL](http://winningwp.com/best-testimonial-plugins-for-wordpress/) for some cool wordpress testimonial plugins.

Comment: It's not working.
I don't know why but I somehow can access to all testimonials true changing the URL
[ domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=testimonial ]
Notices the last keyword.
Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

in default there will not be a Testimonial tab like pages and post. To get a Testimonial tab you have to install a plugin
below given plugin have that option, that one you can use
https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonials-widget/screenshots/
https://ps.w.org/testimonials-widget/assets/screenshot-11.png?rev=1007473
thanks
    [image]

Comment: It's not working.
I don't know why but I somehow can access to all testimonials true changing the URL
[ domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=testimonial ]
Notices the last keyword.
Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Reason : Why not there?**

You have to check is it enable or not. (wordpress.com)

**Solution**

Step -1 fixed by disabling and re-enabling the Testimonial content type.

Step -2 Go to  Settings → Writing → Your Custom Content Types, uncheck the Testimonials option, save your changes. (if already checked).

Step -3  re-check the Testimonials option and save your changes again.

Step -4 Check its available.

**Please check image if can't understand steps :**

[image]